# SQL 2 Joins in one Query

Tags: sql, join

I am having trouble understanding this SQL. I have these 3 tables (see the image below). I need to find a way to extract the name and the maritial status of the person. I know i need 2 Joins, but i cant get it to work.

### Desired Output:

```
John   Married
Mary   Widow
```

### Tables:

**person_per**

```
per_ID   per_FirstName
   1     John
   2     Mary
```

**person_custom**

```
per_ID   status_code
   1         2
   2         4
```

**list_lst**

```
status_code   ???  
     1        Married
     2        Single
     3        Divorced
     4        Widow
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select per_FirstName, l.[status] /* you didn't put a name for that column */
from person_per p
inner join person_custom c on c.per_ID = p.per_ID
inner join list_lst l on l.status_code = c.status_code
```

Comment: if he is a student and that is his homework then he will never learn, its up to him if he wants to learn or not. people here just trying to help without going into the details of the others

Comment: No, its not my homework. I am trying to learn SQL, because i am trying to adapt an opensource CRM to my church. I know some PHP, but i am havimg some trouble with SQL (i never took sql classes). The software iscalled churchcrm.

Thank you for you help!